# Transforming velocity vector from its one coordinates system to another coordinate

Tags: vectors

If I have a velocity of an object in its local coordinates, and I have the velocity of another object

how would I transform the velocity vector to the coordinates of the second object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simple looking question touches an amazing amount of physics.

If the velocities are small compared to the speed of light, then have a look at [Galilean transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation).

Otherwise it gets more complicated, see [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group), [Poincaré transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group).